# How do you increase the heap size used by the GWT Maven Plugin when IntelliJ's "make" calls it?

Tags: gwt, maven, intellij-idea, out-of-memory

I am upgrading my project from GWT 2.3.0 to 2.4.0.  As a side affect, my GWT compilation fails because it runs out of memory.  I searched online and found that you can specify additional memory parameters inside of the Maven pom.xml file (by adding a configuration block) like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <extraJvmArgs>-XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Xmx1024m</extraJvmArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This works if I build directly with Maven, but when I build with IntelliJ, it still runs out of memory.  When I view the process details on my OS while IntelliJ is compiling, it is still using -Xmx128m as a flag passed to the JVM.

How can I configure the max memory that the plugin can use inside of IntelliJ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IntelliJ's GWT plugin will do the build using its own settings and won't use the ones in the Maven plugin.

You need to go to the projects settings (see http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/gwt-facet.html)

You can increase your 'Compiler Maximum Heap' there.

Comment: So basically you do "File" -> "Project Structure" -> "Modules" -> "GWT" and there is a field for the max heap size!  Nice!  Thanks!

Comment: IntelliJ at this moment doesn't contain a GWT plugin. How can I edit these settings?

Answer (score 3):

In the console before building you should use these parameters:

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-Dgwt.extraJvmArgs="-Xms1g -Xmx2g"
```

Using -xmx etc. won't help anything becaus GWT seems to use it's own JVM inside Maven which doesn't get those parameter values. However, -Dgwt.extraJvmArg will be passed down to GWT.